# Logilink RS232c USB-to-Serial converter software

Tags: windows-7, usb, serial-port, rs232

I have a device with RS232 that works with a PCI board, however when I install a Logilink USB-to-Serial converter, I stop receiving data from my device. How do I resolve this?

- **PCI Board configuration:** 
   [image: Screenshot1]
- **Logilink Converter configuration:** 
   [image: Screenshot2]

Comment: Did you install the drivers for the USB-to-Serial converter?

Comment: Yes, I have installed it. The computer has recognized the converter but it isn't receiving data from the device.

Comment: I've only used USB-TTL converters, but shouldn't the configuration between the two be the same (BAUD, Parity, Data & Stop bits, DTR, RTS, etc.)?  Your question and title are asking different things - if you need a program that can change these, have you tried [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html)?

Comment: If these (slightly doctored) screenshots are showing the two ends (it's not clear), then the configuration parameters _must_ match... "_baudrate_" and "_parity_" are critical, and the flow control (RTS / CTS) are also important if you're trying to use them (disable flow control if you're not trying to use them).

Comment: I just wanted to show that if I connect the device directly to the board my configuration is baudrate: 2400, Parity: odd, temporisation & circuit dtr: on (i need my converter to work with the same parameters because my device uses software handshaking) while when i connect the device with the converter the parameters i mentionned above change and the device stop sending data to my program.

Comment: I have changed the parameters manually (baudrate, parity, DTR, temporisation ) to force it work but still no good result.

Comment: Step 1: just to check the RS232 interface, can you connect the Tx pin to the Rx pin with a piece of wire, and disable all flow control... if you type a character, it should be echoed back to you. disconnect Tx/Rx, and the characters should not be echoed any more. Please confirm that you see this behaviour.

Comment: Which one of them, the one on the converter or the one in PCI board?

Comment: @HassaneBry Either/or

Comment: @Attie I've check the step, it's how you described. I confirm.

Comment: @HassaneBry - apologies for not being clear, please confirm this for both ends (PCI card and the converter you mentioned)

Comment: If this behaves as I've described above, then you should have two functional interfaces... the next step is looking into why they are not communicating. You said the PCI card is RS232, can you provide any information on the "_converter_" you mentioned? i.e: Is it TTL / 3.3v? If so, then it is not directly compatible with [RS-232 signalling levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232#Voltage_levels), even if some RS-232 interfaces work with it.

Comment: No worries @Attie, my converter is Adaptateur USB 2.0, série LogiLink AU0002E - [1x SUB-D mâle 9 pôles - 1x USB 2.0 type A mâle] • Référence article: 558713. The thing is that the same converter has worked for other devices which was connected to the same card. It's only one device which is not working for now.

Comment: I have changed my converter, and now when i type the command "mode" i can see the configuration i wanted for the port. thus, i still can get the data. I used a serial port scanner (software) in order to see if there's communication. And yes, the communication is ok until I press the button on my device to send data to my data acquisition software. Once that button pressed the communication stop and i can't collect the data i want. Please note that the device is sending correctly the data when it is connected to the PCI CARD, it refuses only with the converters. Please HELP